# How to Solve Authentication issue when pushing Docker Image using Maven to Private repository

Tags: maven, docker, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to push my docker image which is build using maven in my local to my public/private repository in Docker Cloud/Docker Hub.But I am getting Index response didn't contain any endpoints when it's try to Push.Below is sample config of my pom.xml.

I am not sure which configuration I am missing here.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/dockercloudappstation</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <!-- <dockerHost>tcp://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost> -->
                <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
                <!-- <registryUrl>https://hub.docker.com/</registryUrl> -->
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- <targetPath>/</targetPath> -->
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>build-image</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>build</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>tag-image-version</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>tag</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- <image>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</image> -->
                        <image>${docker.image.prefix}/dockercloudappstation</image>
                        <newName>hub.docker.com/${docker.image.prefix}/dockercloudappstation</newName>
                        <!-- <serverId>docker-hub</serverId> -->
                        <pushImage>true</pushImage>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>tag-image-latest</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>tag</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- <image>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</image> -->
                        <image>${docker.image.prefix}/dockercloudappstation</image>
                        <newName>hub.docker.com/${docker.image.prefix}/dockercloudappstation:latest</newName>
                        <pushImage>true</pushImage>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                  <id>push-image</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>push</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                  <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
                    <!-- <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/dockercloudappstation</imageName> -->
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Error Log:

```
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exception caught
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:130)
    at com.spotify.docker.TagMojo.execute(TagMojo.java:44)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: Index response didn't contain any endpoints
    at com.spotify.docker.client.AnsiProgressHandler.progress(AnsiProgressHandler.java:52)
    at com.spotify.docker.Utils$DigestExtractingProgressHandler.progress(Utils.java:150)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.ProgressStream.tail(ProgressStream.java:77)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.push(DefaultDockerClient.java:1040)
    at com.spotify.docker.Utils.pushImage(Utils.java:83)
    at com.spotify.docker.TagMojo.execute(TagMojo.java:119)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:128)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `settings.xml` for your maven settings configuration and add here server with your credentials. Usually this file is located in `.m2` folder so add here something like:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>docker-hub</id>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

This settings shouldn't be (and AFAIK can't be) in `pom.xml` because of security issues.

If you are interested in more secure option you can encrypt your password like in example [here](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin#using-encrypted-passwords-for-authentication).

---

You have too messy `pom.xml`. Try to start with simplest `pom.xml` configuration. Check [springio example](https://hub.docker.com/r/springio/) and change `springio` property to your `docker hub` repo.

```
<properties>
   <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
<!--  <registryUrl></registryUrl> is optional and defaults to https://index.docker.io/v1/ in the Spotify docker-client dependency. -->
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I have provided my docker hub credentials in my setting.xml. But now at the final step while trying to push Im getting Index response didn't contain any endpoints exception.

Comment: What is your `registryUrl` defined in `pom.xml`?

Comment: Have you tried `<registryUrl>https://index.docker.io/v1/</registryUrl>`?

Comment: I haven't tried this option.But eventhough if i don't use this URL explicitly system is trying to connect above URL only.

Comment: I have added simple example. try `mvn clean package docker:build -DpushImage` and let me know what happened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127658/discussion-between-vladodemcak-and-springbootlearner).

Comment: Thanks for your guidance I have updated working configuration.I have moved image,newName configuration at the configuration level and removed them from goals.